# How to format Ext2 in Windows XP?

Tags: cygwin, format, ext2

I want to format my USB stick to ext2. I have following tools installed. But don't know how to use them for my case:

- Cygwin – I'm just a starter and not surely know how to use. (`mkfs` is also not included.)
- Ext2Fsd – Don't know how to format Ext2. I found `Change Partition Type` and there are many types which I don't know.

Can anyone please guide me with steps on any of above tools (or) are there any other solutions?

Comment: Partition manager can do it, and it has a trial...

Comment: What version do you mean? Are you please sure for "USB" drive? Because i have Partition "MAGIC" (not "Manager") 8.0 Version and it also supports Ext2/3 but don't support USB drives.. :(

Comment: Why would you want to format a USB drive as ext2?

Comment: partition manager, version 9 could do it, now up to 11

Comment: Do you please mean "Paragon" PM, right?? Coz i'm afraid i'll get wrong one as there are a lot Partition Managers out there.

Comment: Yes I do (padding).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Possibly for use as a permanent drive in a router for its lack of journaling.

Answer (score 10):

Install the `e2fsprogs` package from the installer and then you get the `mke2fs` (mke2fs.exe) command.  Then, read [this starting at the section "POSIX devices"](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) to learn what device to tell it to format.

I've never done this.  Be careful.

Comment: Now i have installed `e2fsprogs`. (But there is no `e2fsprogs` inside Cygwin call, by pressing "Tab" also. Is is normal?) Then how can i get `mke2fs` ? Please guide me on further steps.

Comment: @4lvin: mke2fs is part of e2fsprogs. Like Word is part of MS Office. There is no program called e2fsprogs.

Comment: So you mean, now i should have called and seen `mke2fs` inside Cygwin, right? But there, "no" `mke2fs` is up inside my Cygwin. Why? (or) What should i do next?

Comment: Does /sbin/mke2fs works?

Comment: /sbin/??? From which location you mean? There is no folder inside my default location i'm reaching at the starting of `Cygwin`.

Comment: Ah.. there is no `mke2fs` under `/usr/sbin/`

Comment: According to this - http://cygwin.com/packages/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs-1.35-3 - it's `/usr/sbin/mke2fs.exe`.

Comment: `e2fsprogs` puts `mke2fs` in `/usr/sbin`, which is not in the default path.

Answer (score -1):

sorry - formatting on answer is nasty

```
    echo -e "\nFormatting USB Key ${usbKey}"
    yy=`date +'%d%m%y'`
    echo "usbPath=${usbPath}"
    dosUSBPath_=`echo ${usbPath}|cut -d "/" -f3`; 
    dosUSBPath=`echo "${dosUSBPath_}:"`
    /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/format.com ${dosUSBPath} /fs:fat32 /v:${yy} /q /x /y 
    echo -e "\nDrive contents now are :"; ls -lrt ${usbPath}
```

Will format the MicroSD card

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/format.com d: /fs:fat32 /v:210115 /q /x /y
```

The type of the file system is FAT32.
QuickFormatting 7600M
Initializing the File Allocation Table (FAT)...
Format complete.
       7.4 GB total disk space.
       7.4 GB are available.

```
    4,096 bytes in each allocation unit.
1,941,503 allocation units available on disk.

       32 bits in each FAT entry.
```

Volume Serial Number is 2068-BD0A

Comment: In the future you can just click the "edit" link below your post to fix the formatting after posting.

Comment: The OP wanted to format in ext2, not FAT32.