# Command: How to format Ext2/Ext3 with Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, ext3, ext2, ext4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format Ext2 in WinXP?](https://superuser.com/questions/314997/how-to-format-ext2-in-winxp)

I just installed Cygwin, then i want to format my usb drive to Ext2/3/4 or any other Linux FS.

What do i need?
And, what is the command?

Comment: Why am i wrong??????

Comment: How is the is a programming question?

Comment: Can't answer the Cygwin question, but you could use a gparted live-cd, or any Linux live-cd that includes gparted, such as Ubuntu.

Comment: @Joe Internet: Thanks for your alternative suggestions but i just wanna know how to do with Cygwin.